# Explanation for assigning Objective-C NSNumber object to int variable?

Tags: objective-c, key-value, instance-variables, key-value-coding

Can anyone explain why this works in Objective-C? I would expect it to give an error since an object is being assigned to an int variable. I get that it does work, and this is great, but I am missing why this is allowed?

```
int i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
```

Furthermore, this seems to store the wrong value (ie, on my system when I print out the value of "i" using NSLog I get "252711" instead of 123); however, only when the variable is declared and assigned in my main code. If I declare it as an instance variable of an object and then use Key-Value coding to assign it a value, it works properly:

Object instance variables...

```
@interface myObject : NSObject
{
    int anInt;
}
```

Main code...

```
[myObject setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:123] forKey:@"anInt"];
NSLog(@"%@", [myObject valueForKey:@"anInt"]);
```

This code prints out "123" as expected, but I'm not sure why given that when using a seemingly similar approach above it does not work properly.

Comment: You need to learn the difference between objects and primitive types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it doesnt "work" and there is a compiler warning about it. the reason it can be compiled is that the `NSNumber` class method `numberWithInt` returns a pointer, which can be implicitly converted to `int`. When you print it out you are getting the ***address*** where the objective-c object was allocated.

the `SetValue:forKey:` method doesnt take an `int` parameter, it takes an `id` which is just a pointer to a generic Objective-C object. Key-Value coding is taking care of assigning the `intValue` of the `NSNumber` object for you.

Answer (score 2):

When you executing the code:

```
int i = [NSNumber numberWithInt:123];
```

You just assigning **pointer** value to int.
`numberWithInt:` returns `NSNumber*` and it's a **pointer**, pointing to some place in memory where `NSNumber` object allocated.
And now value of `i` is not a `123` but decimal representation of `NSNumber*` **pointer**.
Read more about [pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) in **C/Objective-C.**